# SQL Allocating records

Tags: sql

I got 3 tables:
`DroneStore`, `OperatorStore`, `Operations`*(Junction table)*

I have independent data in `DroneStore` and `OperatorStore`, and I would like to allocate 1 of the drone in `DroneStore` to any one of the operator in `OperatorStore` with the junction table.

Could someone help me with this?

This is what I got with the table:

```
CREATE TABLE DroneStore (
id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
name TEXT,
classType int,
rescue BOOLEAN,
operator INT,
);

CREATE TABLE OperatorStore (
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
firstName TEXT,
familyName TEXT,
dateOfBirth DATE,
droneLicense INT,
rescueEndorsement BOOLEAN,
operations INT,
);

CREATE TABLE Operations (
operatorId INT NOT NULL,
droneId INT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(droneId) REFERENCES DroneStore(id),
FOREIGN KEY(operatorId) REFERENCES OperatorStore(id)
);
```

Comment: Can you provide your type/version of SQL and an example of the table structures, sample data and expected results?

Comment: This should be a simple matter of adding a record to the `Operations` table that has an `operatorID` from `OperatorStore` and a `droneID` from `DroneStore`.

Comment: So each operator gets one drone assigned, but that one drone is the same for every operator? That is, in the end there are as many records in `operations` as there are in `operatorstore`? Is this correct so far? And that single drone, does it have to be one in particular or just any?

Comment: This is an assignment-problem. Hint: use not exists.Hint2: enumerate the allocatable items (row_number()) , and match them 1to1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it does not matter which operator or drone you choose and there is data in both the `OperatorStore` and `DroneStore` tables, then you can execute this to assign a single drone to a single operator.

```
INSERT INTO Operations (operatorId , droneId)
SELECT TOP 1 OS.id , DS.id 
FROM OperatorStore AS OS 
                        CROSS JOIN 
                                  DroneStore AS DS
```

Also nice question formatting. Keep up the good work!

Comment: Please, please, please do not use comma-syntax JOINs. I've heard a puppy gets kicked every time that happens.

Comment: Sorry, I've been working on an old application that was written pre-2008. I'll update that... Okay should be in a the correct format now.

Comment: I think you just saved a puppy. :-)

Comment: Thanks, this solution works for me. I do also change a little bit for other requirement which required assigning to selected target.